# Static Class Not maintaining its state C#

Tags: c#, static, web-garden

My question here is why my feed_expiration_date datetime variable becomes null on each request only in server environment it works perfectly on local environment I have a web garden (8 process workers) on both local and server environment.

actually since I have 8 process worker so I have different process ID for example PID:1234 and initially it has the feed_expiration_date value set to some date and when user again request the page with in the expiration period time if the process gets same PID: 1234 then  PID:1234 should hold its previous value. in my local it is working as expected but on the server environment it is not working any help would be highly appreciated

```
 public static class CacheManager
    {    
        public static ClientData ClientDataCache
            {
                get
                {
                    return GetClientDataCacheByID(HostInstanceID);
                }
            }
        
            public static ClientData GetClientDataCacheByID(int instance_id)
            {
                try
                {
                    ClientData data = null;
                    if (instance_id != 0)
                        data = client_cache_data_dictionary.ContainsKey(instance_id) ? client_cache_data_dictionary[instance_id] : null;
        
                    if (data == null || data.GlobalSettingsCache == null || DateTime.UtcNow > data.date_cached.AddHours(1))
                        return GenerateClientData();
        
                    return data;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        
            private static ClientData GenerateClientData()
            {
                lock (InstanceLocker)
                {
                    ClientData data = null;
                    int instance_id = HostInstanceID;
                    if (instance_id != 0)
                        data = client_cache_data_dictionary.ContainsKey(instance_id) ? client_cache_data_dictionary[instance_id] : null;
        
                    if (data == null || data.GlobalSettingsCache == null || DateTime.UtcNow > data.date_cached.AddHours(1))
                    {
                        data = new ClientData(true);
        
                        if (data != null && data.InstanceID > 0)
                        {
                            int id = data.InstanceID;
                            HostInstanceID = id;
                            client_cache_data_dictionary[id] = data;  // To prevent race conditions, this has to happen prior to client_data_cache_lock_dictionary[id] = new object();
                            client_data_cache_lock_dictionary[id] = new object();  // This has to happen 2nd, not first
        
                            if (Portals.Utils.IsEC2)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (!global_cache_mgr_init)
                                    {
                                        GlobalCacheManager.GlobalCacheManager.Initialize(GlobalCacheManager.Enumerations.SystemLocations.AdminPortal, !Portals.Utils.IsEC2 ? "us-west-2" : null);
                                        global_cache_mgr_init = true;
                                        GlobalCacheManager.GlobalCacheManager.Start();
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    Emails.SendAdminEmail("Error Init/Start GCM on ClientCache.cs", ex.StackTrace);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Portals.Utils.LogErrorFeed("ReadGSFromDB","true PID: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Portals.Utils.LogErrorFeed("ReadGSFromCache", "true PID: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            }
    public class ClientData
    {
            public ClientData(bool initdata = false) {
                if (initdata) IntializeClientData();
            }
        private List<SurveysAndFeaturesFeedResult> surveyAndFeaturesFeeds = null;
        public DateTime date_cached { get; set; }
    
            public DateTime? feed_expiration_date { get;set;}
           private object surveys_features_generate_locker = new object();
    public void GenerateSurveysAndFeaturesCache(bool force_refresh = false)
            {
                if(this.InstanceID != 0)
                {
                    lock(surveys_features_generate_locker)
                    {
                        if (this.surveyAndFeaturesFeeds == null || force_refresh)
                        {
                            this.surveyAndFeaturesFeeds = CakeFeed.GetSurveysAndFeaturesFeedResult();
                            this.feed_expiration_date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(this.global_settings.CakeFeedCacheDurationHoursCKM);
                            
                        } 
                            
                    }
    
                    if(force_refresh && this.surveyAndFeaturesFeeds != null)
                    {
                        Portals.Utils.RefreshPortals();
                    }
                }
            }
    public List<SurveysAndFeaturesFeedResult> SurveysAndFeaturesFeed
            {
                get
                {
                    if(this.global_settings.EnablePresentIcon && (surveyAndFeaturesFeeds == null || feed_expiration_date == null || feed_expiration_date < DateTime.UtcNow))
                    {
                        GenerateSurveysAndFeaturesCache();
                    }
                    
                    
                    return (surveyAndFeaturesFeeds == null) ? new List<SurveysAndFeaturesFeedResult>() : surveyAndFeaturesFeeds.ToList();
                }
            }
    }
    }
```

And from handler.ashx I call this as `CacheManager.ClientDataCache.SurveysAndFeaturesFeed.OrderByDescending(x=>x.PublishDate).ToList();`

Comment: Your feed expiration date is in a normal class, not a static one. So my presumption would be that this class is scoped and resets after every request

Comment: Yup I also thinks the same but why it is working correctly on my local ?